# Are we making tags for almost everything?

Tags: discussion

I was just looking though some of the tags and have seen a few that made me thing twice.  The first one I saw was a Buick error code.  P0602.  My first thought was, that error code is probably being used by quite a few manufacturers and there is a very good chance that it doesn't mean the same thing on a Buick as it does for a Honda or Ford.

The other one I saw was ZZR600.  A model of Kawasaki.  It seemed odd but I suppose it makes sense, if the issue that is being tagged with a model is unique to the model.  Many of the problems people are throwing out there are universal across platforms.  Some of them can apply to a lawn mower all the way out to tractor.

My question is, are we intentionally making tags for all models of vehicle?

As well, are we making tags for error codes or is this one just a strange one off anomaly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, and Yes.

Tags for make a model are useful for people who only want to find those questions. It's even more apparent once the site has a lot of questions a day as people can subscribe to tags the are interested or knowledgeable in.

OBD II standardize the codes for cars and light trucks some time in the late nighties. After that all the codes mean basically the same thing across all manufactures. So a P0300 means the same on a Ford, Chevy, Honda, Kia etc. There can still be manufacture specific codes but even they have to be formatted a specific way.

Answer (score 3):

I will quite often create tags which don't exist to help breakout a person's problem better. Hopefully this will help someone find an existing Q&A instead of trying to duplicate a Question. The way I see it is, you can put up to five tags to a question ... why not utilize all five if you can justify it. It can only help in the end.